# Do there exist nonconstant functions such that...

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis

Do there exist nonconstant real valued functions $f$ and $g$ such that the expression:
$$f(x) -v/g(x)$$
is maximized at $x = v$ for all positive real $v$?

Comment: Functions on $\mathbb{R}$ or on the positive reals? In the latter case, $- \log x$ and $x$.

Comment: Function on $\mathbb R$. Positivity is for $v$ only.

Comment: Motivation for the question?

Comment: @Yemon: might be a homework, might be curiosity. I don't see any deep context here but it's tricky.

Comment: Do we need $g$ to be non-vanishing? And what is this for?

Comment: @Leandro, I understand your point and the homological (2nd) answer probably fits your point of view. Does EDO mean ODE?

Comment: @WadimI, I completely forget to translate, sorry :) 
 EDO = Equações diferenciais ordinárias. 
 

Comment: @Wadim, thank you for point the confusion in my last comment. But I thought he was looking for the functions. So before read the Gjerdji solutions, I thought the problem could be approached by a ODE. Define a function $h(x,y)=x-\frac{v}{y}$ and try to get the solution maximizing $h\circ\gamma(t)$, over all differentiable curves such $\nabla h\circ\gamma(v)\cdot\gamma'(v)=0$ for all $v\in\mathbb R$. That is the ODE I would like to consider. But I am not sure if it is nice approach. 

Comment: Yemon, a probabilistic motivation may exist, see my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take $f(x)=(x+1)e^{-x}$ and $g(x)=e^x$, then $f(x)-v/g(x)=(x+1-v)e^{-x}$ and the derivative with respect to $x$ is $(v-x)e^{-x}$.

Comment: Doesn't this work for *any* real $v$? (So, you do much more!)

Comment: May I suggest you to take a more realistic name for MO? (I am very sorry for making a joke with your present one in a comment above but you don't give me an option to cite your answer correctly.)

Answer (score 8):

By the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality, when $v$ is positive
$$-|x|^{\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{v}{|x|^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$ is maximized at $x=v$ and $x=-v$.

Comment: Nice! 123456789 (I needed some extra characters)

Comment: Nice! $       $

Comment: It is not defined at $x=0$.  I think the question was about functions on the whole real line.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f$ be arbitrary (but non-constant, real-valued, and differentiable), let $h$ be any antiderivative of 
$f'(x)/x$, and let $g=1/h$; then $f'(v)g'(v)=v$, so $f-v/g$ has a critical point at $x=v$. Now you can look for conditions under which that critical point is a maximum.

Answer (score 1):

The following calculation suggests that a nice probability interpretation may exist for any solution one can construct.

$u(x) = f(x) - v/g(x)$ and all its $x$ derivatives are linear functions of $v$ with coefficients that are functions of $x$.

Thus, to have an extremum at $x=v$ the first derivative $u'$ must be of the form $(v-x)M(x)$. Integrating the $v$-degree 0 and 1 parts of this equation produces $f$ and (the reciprocal of) $g$.  Algebraically this will be equivalent to Gerry's solution.

The interesting points are that:

1. To have a maximum we need $M(x) \geq 0$, so $M$ can be interpreted as a density.
2. The total mass $\int M$ has to be finite in order for $g(x)$ to exist on the whole real line. This is so that we can choose a constant of integration larger (in absolute value) than the total mass, when computing $1/g = C + \int M$.  Thus, $M$ is a sort of probability measure, and literally is one when $\int M = 1$.
3. $f$ is calculated as integral of $xM$, ie., an expected value of $x$.
4. $1/g$ is calculated using the integral of $M$, ie., a probability.

So there might be a simple probability inequality lurking behind most of the solutions.